# How to express "fizzle out" in German

Tags: translation, word-usage, english-to-german, german-to-english

I'm am struggling with the right way to express, "to fizzle out", in German. Let me give some example sentences:

1. We were very good friends at first, but over the years, our friendship fizzled out.
2. The game was very exciting at first, but sort of fizzled out (got boring) at the end.

Now, I see "versanden" oder "im Sande verlaufen" as a possibility, and I am pretty sure that the first sentence can be translated as

1. Wir waren am Anfang sehr gute Freunde, aber über die Jahre hinweg ist unsere Freundschaft versandet.

But today I tried to use "versandet" in the second context, and I got funny looks. I am therefore confused as to the correct way to express "to fizzle out" in both of these contexts in German. Thanks for any help you can provide me!

Comment: You may have to consider that metaphors in one language may be mapped to ones in another language, but the range is often not the same.

Comment: For your second sentence, is *... aber dann wurde es langweilig* not a solution? Do you exclude a direct translation of *got boring*?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann no, I understand langweilig is a perfectly fine solution. However, I like to challenge myself and get a deeper understanding of the language.

Comment: "Wir waren am Anfang sehr gute Freunde, aber über die Jahre hinweg ist unsere Freundschaft versandet." That doesn't sound right, but "Wir waren am Anfang sehr gute Freunde, aber über die Jahre hinweg ist unsere Freundschaft im Sande verlaufen." would work. But for the game neither of your suggestions would work.

Comment: In context of friendship and relationship one can also use the expression "Man hat sich auseinander gelebt".

Comment: Note that *versanden* and *im Sande verlaufen* are definitely two different things.

Comment: @tofro Could you be kind enough to provide more details?

Comment: *versanden* can be used both literally and figuratively (but rather the former, e.g. "Der See/die Bucht/der Flusslauf ist im Lauf der Jahre versandet"). *Im Sande verlaufen* is very unlikely to be used literally.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

German has a similar “going flat” metaphor, only instead of soda or a chemical reaction, we refer to deflating balloons:

> ... die Luft raus...

It probably works better in your second example:

> Das Spiel war zuerst spannend, aber dann war irgendwie die Luft raus.“

But it can also be used for relationships like in your first example:

> Über die Jahre war dann die Luft raus.

Other metaphors are

> - sich totlaufen (for trends or fads)
> - sich überlebt haben (for relationships and trends)
> - an/den Reiz verlieren (for everything originally considered attractive and exciting, particularly activities and hobbies, e.g. your game, but also for (romantic) relationships or persons)

Comment: I'm fairly certain 'die Luft raus' originally referred to tires, not balloons. (But I can't find a source for that unfortunately)

Comment: Whatever deflates...

Comment: I am a native German speaker and can't recall any occasion I ever heard 'sich totlaufen' in a sentence... this might be a local expression?

Comment: @Kinaeh native speaker as well, familiar with the expression (hence listed here), but I can’t pinpoint a specific context. See https://www.dwds.de/wb/totlaufen.

Comment: @Kinaeh I'd say sich totlaufen is used more often for political movements or progress: "Die Aufklärung der Judenverfolgung hat sich totgelaufen" but the usage is rather rare.

Comment: Can you use "die Puste ausgehen" here as well?

Comment: @TimSeguine that’s different. It is used for when you can’t sustain a (physical) exertion, e.g. when in the 75th minute of a football game the players are visibly exhausted. It translates to being short of breath. It’s usually not used in the context given by the OP.

Comment: @Stephie Also never heard 'sich totlaufen', though the expression is easily understandable.

Comment: I'd use 'die Luft ist raus' for something that now lacks hype, i.e. something that was previously mono-thematically interesting or engaging. 'Unsere Beziehung war sehr körperlich - aber nach ein paar Monaten war die Luft raus' - So i fully support it's use in the game context above, but if used in context of a relationship, i feel it somehow demeans the relationship by insinuating that it was built on hype/built on one aspect - this might be the intended effect, but otherwise it's dangerous.

Answer (score 16):

When something is "im Sande verlaufen" it means that nothing more came from it. So it doesn't work for a game that had an active end (like a referee blowing the whistle), but it could be used for chess-by-mail where one or the other doesn't reliably answer anymore and then it just fades away.

"Es ist langweilig geworden" would actually describe the game situation much better, or use "sich dahinziehen": "Das Spiel war Anfang spannend, aber es zog sich dann zum Ende hin."

Answer (score 12):

In some contexts "einschlafen" can be used.

A typical example:

> Wir haben uns noch ein paarmal getroffen, aber der Kontakt ist dann eingeschlafen.

Comment: But this certainly won’t fit for a game that gets boring. OP seems to struggle with the latter?

Comment: 'Das Spiel ist eingeschlafen' works for me.

Answer (score 8):

For me the most natural/common ways of expressing it would be:

1.) Wir waren sehr gute Freunde, aber im Laufe der Zeit haben wir uns *aus den Augen verloren* (lost sight of each other)
OR
...haben wir *den Kontakt verloren* (lost contact)

2.) Das Spiel [...] hat am Ende *an Spannung verloren* (lost suspense)

You see, if something fades or becomes less, you mostly can use *verlieren* (lose)

Answer (score 3):

I think one of the most natural metaphors would be "Our friendship fell asleep"

1. Wir waren früher richtig gute Freunde, aber über die Jahre ist unsere Freundschaft irgendwann eingeschlafen.
2. Das Spiel war am Anfang noch spannend, aber hat sich dann (in Belanglosigkeit/Langeweile) verlaufen

Another option for the second case could be "Die ganze Spannung hat sich in Wohlgefallen aufgelöst." Which is probably less "fizzled out" and more "just ceased to exist"

Comment: negative things like problems can 'sich in Wohlgefallen auflösen' (vanish into good feelings), a friendship could only be said to do so sarcastically, imo

Comment: @bukwyrm I was thinking of the case where the friendship got bad before it ended... But you are right, it is mostly used for problems

Answer (score 2):

*verpuffen* could also fit here.

Wir waren am Anfang sehr gute Freunde, aber über die Jahre hinweg ist unsere Freundschaft verpufft.

*sich verflüchtigen* would be similar, both express the fleeting, thinning nature of the thing in question. (*fizzling out* is also a slow dieing of a fire)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sich legen` in this case.

> Wir waren am Anfang sehr gute Freunde, aber über die Jahre hinweg hat
>   sich das gelegt.

It's a pretty versatile expression but in this particular case I would actually prefer the answer provided by Lennart Gerson `sich aus den Augen verlieren`.

For more examples refer to number six on https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/legen#Bedeutung6

Answer (score 0):

abklingen

Wir waren am Anfang sehr gute Freunde, aber über die Jahre hinweg ist unsere Freundschaft abgeklungen.

Comment: Hm. As a native speaker, I would not use “abklingen” for personal relationships. And how about the OP’s second example of a computer game?

Comment: @Stephie Wie klingt es? Unhöflich oder falsch?

Comment: @peterh falsch. Eine Entzündung , eine Krankheit oder ein Brennstab kann abklingen, Beziehungen nicht.

Comment: @Stephie Danke schön! :)

Comment: Und was ist mit dem Spiel, das langweilig wurde? Im übrigen gebe ich Stephie recht: Freundschaften klingen nicht ab.

Comment: As a native speaker, I think this is fine to use with friendships.

Answer (score 0):

A nice expression you can use with **friendships** specifically is:

> Die Freundschaft erkaltete.

Literally: *It cooled down*.

This also fits well with the temperature metaphor of having a "warm" relationship vs a "cold" relationship with someone.

Answer (score 0):

'Langweilig' passt für das zweite Beispiel

Das Spiel war zuerst interessant wurde dann aber langweilig. Oder ... wurde zum Ende hin langweilig.

Es kann auch zum ersten Beispiel angewandt werden:
Wir waren erst gute Freude aber über die Jahre langweilten wir uns.

Answer (score 0):

Ein Fußballspiel kann zerfasern oder verfransen - das passt jedoch eher zu einem Spiel, dass am Ende in eine Fehlpassorgie ausartet, als zu einem Kick, bei dem sich nichts mehr tut, weil beide das Ergebnis akzeptieren. In letzterem Fall fände ich auch versanden nicht verkehrt.

Neben Stephies Antworten zur Freundschaft möchte ich noch das Einschlafen stellen, welches sowohl zu einer Freundschaft als auch zu einem Fußballspiel passen kann.